Why AMP not working in Next14 Custom server?
I used to run my development environment using the default next run dev command, and the AMP version of my project worked fine. However, after switching to a custom Next.js server, the AMP stopped working and now only shows an HTML page without any styling.
Specs:

Next.js 14.2.3
React.js 18.3.1
Pages route

Here is my custom server code:
const { loadEnvConfig, processEnv } = require("@next/env")
const loadedEnvConfig = loadEnvConfig(dirname, false)
processEnv(loadedEnvConfig.loadedEnvFiles)
process.env.NODE_ENV = "development"
process.chdir(dirname)

const { createServer } = require("http")
const { parse } = require("url")
const next = require("next")

const dev = true
const hostname = process.env.HOSTNAME || "localhost"
const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000
const app = next({ dev, hostname, port })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(() => {
    createServer(async (req, res) => {
        try {
            // Be sure to pass `true` as the second argument to `url.parse`.
            // This tells it to parse the query portion of the URL.
            const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)

            await handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
        } catch (err) {
            console.error("Error occurred handling", req.url, err)
            res.statusCode = 500
            res.end("internal server error")
        }
    })
        .once("error", (err) => {
            console.error(err)
            process.exit(1)
        })
        .listen(port, () => {
            console.log(`\x1b[32m\x1b[1m>  Ready on http://${hostname}:${port} \x1b[0m`)
        })
})

For your information, I am currently using Next.js 14.2.3. When I switched back to Next.js 13.1.6 while using the custom server, AMP worked correctly. I suspect it's a problem with Next.js 14.
